# Laptop with broken screen / BIOS

Tags: laptop, bios, hdmi, vga, laptop-display

I have a laptop with a broken screen.

I know I can use the HDMI and VGA outputs to use it, but I need to access the BIOS.

I have tried everything I could find on the Internet (even here, on stack- sites) but there was no way to get the BIOS on an external monitor.

The only path left would be to replace the screen, but I thought: Would it be possible convert the signal coming from the motherboard's 40 pin connector to an HDMI or VGA cable?

Does something like a "40-pin-to-HDMI" cable exist?

Comment: I am quite sure you need to replace the screen.

Comment: No BIOS on VGA if laptop lid is closed? I find that strange. My Lenovo Thinkpads allow this with the VGA connector on the laptop, and with any display output if docked.

Comment: Nope... No BIOS on VGA and no BIOS on HDMI... Even with closed lid...

Answer (score 0):

To get access to the drive of your laptop you can simply remove it and connect it as an external one to another machine if there is no boot time encryption involved.

The connection between your motherboard and the screen is mostly likely digital so that I assume there is no VGA signal over that 40 pin connection.

There is no HDMI standard required just to connect your motherboard to your laptop screen.

If you don't want to replace the screen, get yourself the laptop model again and use the laptop with the working screen to access its BIOS.

Use the same series of key strokes to switch over the laptop with the broken screen to use an external monitor instead of the internal one during boot time.